# Set value of first item in slice in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, slice, mask, argmax

So I would like make a slice of a dataframe and then set the value of the first item in that slice without copying the dataframe. For example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(3,1))
df[df[0]>0][0] = 0
```

The slice here is irrelevant and just for the example and will return the whole data frame again. Point being, by doing it like it is in the example you get a setting with copy warning (understandably). I have also tried slicing first and then using ILOC/IX/LOC and using ILOC twice, i.e. something like:

```
df.iloc[df[0]>0,:][0] = 0
df[df[0]>0,:].iloc[0] = 0
```

And neither of these work. Again- I don't want to make a copy of the dataframe even if it id just the sliced version.

EDIT:
It seems there are two ways, using a mask or IdxMax. The IdxMax method seems to work if your index is unique, and the mask method if not. In my case, the index is not unique which I forgot to mention in the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using some of the answers I managed to find a one liner way to do this:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(5,1)))
print df
   0
0  1
1  3
2  0
3  0
4  3
df.loc[(df[0] == 0).cumsum()==1,0] = 1
   0
0  1
1  3
2  1
3  0
4  3
```

Essentially this is using the mask inline with a cumsum.

Answer (score 12):

I think you can use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for get index of first `True` value and then set by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(5,1)))
print (df)
   0
0  1
1  3
2  0
3  0
4  3

print ((df[0] == 0).idxmax())
2

df.loc[(df[0] == 0).idxmax(), 0] = 100
print (df)
     0
0    1
1    3
2  100
3    0
4    3
```

---

```
df.loc[(df[0] == 3).idxmax(), 0] = 200
print (df)
     0
0    1
1  200
2    0
3    0
4    3
```

EDIT:

Solution with not unique index:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(5,1)), index=[1,2,2,3,4])
print (df)
   0
1  1
2  3
2  0
3  0
4  3

df = df.reset_index()
df.loc[(df[0] == 3).idxmax(), 0] = 200
df = df.set_index('index')
df.index.name = None
print (df)
     0
1    1
2  200
2    0
3    0
4    3
```

EDIT1:

Solution with `MultiIndex`:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(5,1)), index=[1,2,2,3,4])
print (df)
   0
1  1
2  3
2  0
3  0
4  3

df.index = [np.arange(len(df.index)), df.index]
print (df)
     0
0 1  1
1 2  3
2 2  0
3 3  0
4 4  3

df.loc[(df[0] == 3).idxmax(), 0] = 200
df = df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

print (df)
     0
1    1
2  200
2    0
3    0
4    3
```

EDIT2:

Solution with double [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame([4,0,4,7,4], index=[1,2,2,3,4])
print (df)
   0
1  4
2  0
2  4
3  7
4  4

mask = (df[0] == 0).cumsum().cumsum()
print (mask)
1    0
2    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: 0, dtype: int32

df.loc[mask == 1, 0] = 200
print (df)
     0
1    4
2  200
2    4
3    7
4    4
```

Comment: Will this work if the second 7 is not directly after the first, i.e., if the result of `cumsum` on the boolean array would have several `1`s?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - thanks, you are right. give me a sec

Comment: I think the most reliable way, and this is only reliable if your index is unique, is to get the index from the slice, then get the first value form the index, and set using that value on the original frame.

Comment: Ah, `idxmax`, very very clever!

Comment: @RexFuzzle - Yes, it works if not consecutive values also, see second solution with different condition.

Comment: Very cool, unfortunately, my index is not unique :( Amended question. Seem the mask method may be the only one in my case. Thank you @jezrael

Comment: I also can't reset the index as I need it back- suppose I could save it and put it back again.

Comment: Why cant be used `reset_index` and `set_index` ?

Comment: I add another solution with `MultiIndex`.

Comment: For non-unique index `iloc`  and `argmax` might be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

print(df)

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

---

Create some arbitrary slice `slc`

```
slc = df[df.A > 2]

print(slc)

   A
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

---

Access the first row of `slc` within `df` by using `index[0]` and `loc`

```
df.loc[slc.index[0]] = 0
print(df)

   A
0  1
1  2
2  0
3  4
4  5
```

Comment: I was hoping to not duplicate any part of the df as it is large and even the slice could be quite big.

Comment: @RexFuzzle you said the slice was arbitrary and I'm assuming already exists.  From that slice, I'm grabbing the first index value and using that to modify the original `df`.

Comment: I think something like `df.loc[slice, another_slice]` should be less memory intensive than `df.loc[slice].loc[:, another_slice]`. This is possible for row and column slicing at the same time but it appears it is not possible to do it row-wise with different conditions. I am not sure actually, maybe what I have in mind doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,1),index=[1,2,2,3,3,3])
df[1] = 0
df.columns=['a','b']
df['b'][df['a']>=0.5]=1
df=df.sort(['b','a'],ascending=[0,1])
df.loc[df[df['b']==0].index.tolist()[0],'a']=0
```

In this method extra copy of the dataframe is not created but an extra column is introduced which can be dropped after processing. To choose any index instead o the first  one you can change the last line as follows

```
df.loc[df[df['b']==0].index.tolist()[n],'a']=0
```

to change any nth item in a slice

df

```
          a  
1  0.111089  
2  0.255633  
2  0.332682  
3  0.434527  
3  0.730548  
3  0.844724
```

df after slicing and labelling them

```
          a  b
1  0.111089  0
2  0.255633  0
2  0.332682  0
3  0.434527  0
3  0.730548  1
3  0.844724  1
```

After changing value of first item in slice (labelled as 0) to 0

```
          a  b
3  0.730548  1
3  0.844724  1
1  0.000000  0
2  0.255633  0
2  0.332682  0
3  0.434527  0
```